# Reading in matrix in R

Tags: r, csv, readr

Is there a way to use read_csv() in R and have all columns read in as doubles and not integers?  I have columns in my matrix that are integers, but I would like them to be viewed by the software as doubles.

Comment: Look at the `col_types` argument to `read_csv`.

Comment: `col_guess` already uses doubles for all numeric columns, e.g. `data_frame(x = rnorm(100), y = rpois(100, 3)) %>% format_csv() %>% read_csv()`

Comment: @G5W I have already tried that by setting the default to doubles, but it still specifies some columns as integers.  I am trying this with a user-defined function, so the number of columns may change depending on what .csv file is input.  Do you know if there is a way to count the number of columns in a file before importing the .csv?

Comment: You could use ncol(read.csv("mydata2.csv", nrows=2))

Comment: I'm having trouble with the col_types: I have been counting the number of columns, and then I put in col_types=rep('d',ncol(read.csv("mydata.csv"))), but it returns an error.